# Stock update Issue

Tags: stock, sku, qty

Running into a problem when updating stock on a configurable product. Basically when one of my stock hits 0 and I do a mass stock update the qty will change but the simple product will remain out of stock. As you can imagine a website will loads of products on this is such a pain as I would have to manually go into each product and change them back into stock.

I tested a stock update on one product. the product went from 0 (out of stock) to qty 20 still out of stock when updating. why will it not automatically change back into stock without manually having to do this?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the (native) reservation inventory system?

Basically, when a product gets sold, it has a reservation status in the database, until the order is completed.

Until then, even if you have 5 products in stock, but 5 are in a reserved state, the available stock is 0.

I use an extension, to disable the reservation system:
https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

Comment: Hello Mario, I have just tested this theory and it still does not work. I made the product qty 1 then bought the item then completed the order and re-updated the product back to 1 with a stock update. showing qty 1 and still out of stock.

Comment: Hmm...have you reindexed?
Also, I think there is a grid column in the orders grid, where you can see the available stock. Maybe you have to activate it first in the grid configurations.

Comment: I have reindexed and cached still nothing. There's no option for stock in the orders grid page. only in the product grid - just an option to show if stock is in or out. Mind blow haha

Comment: Sorry, I meant the products grid. The column is called "Salable quantity".

Comment: Only have the option of stock status and quantity and they were both ticked

Comment: I have no idea why this is...sorry. But I still think, it has something to do with that...

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help! such a weird situation.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

My excel spreadsheet for my stock updates was missing a column 'is_in_stock'

this meant i was only updating the qty and not if the product was in stock or not.

hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.